# How do I add space char to string/char array?

Tags: c

**Here's the overview:** I have to make a cipher that can decrypt and encrypt messages(I have completed that), but the reason we have these ciphers are to encrypt/decrypt messages that are sentences which have whitespaces. Basically, I just need to know when there is whitespace, and when there is, to add that whitespace to the final output.
**#TL;DR:#** How to add whitespace to a String - char output[] ~~~~~~~~~~ that's the String

```
for(int j = 0; input[j] != '\0'; j++){
    int at_index = 0;
    int i = 0;

    //need to check at this point for whitespace
    if(input[j] == ' '){
        output[j] = ' ';
    }
    //gives garbage value

    for(i; alphabet[i] != input[j]; i++){
        ++at_index;
    }

    output[j] = alphabet[at_index + shift];

}
```

Comment: Post the code you have and clearly mark when/where you need to add the space. It can be done in several ways so it depends on the context.

Comment: When you have text that is a cipher, unless the encoding is trivial that lets you identify what the spaces were originally, you will need an alternate method to restore it. A non-trivial cipher will prevent you from being able to determine that from the cipher itself. It is impossible to help further without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you made is that you don't stop the handling of the character after recognizing the whitespace.

This is one possible solution, derived from your source:

```
for (int j = 0; input[j] != '\0'; j++) {
    if (isspace(input[j])) {
        output[j] = input[j];

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; alphabet[i] != input[j]; i++) {
        }
        output[j] = alphabet[i + shift];
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- `at_index` is always the same value as `i` so it's not needed.
- You need to add some logic if the input character is not in the `alphabet`. Since I don't know how your `alphabet` is defined, I can't show it here.
- The `for`-loop can be replaced by some appropriate string function.
- You need some logic to prevent an out-of-bounds access to `alphabet` when reading the shifted character.

Answer (score 0):

I would call a helper function in order to achieve this,

```
white_spaces(char *dest, int size, int num_of_spaces) {
    int len = strlen(dest);
    // for the check i still assume dest tto contain a valid '\0' terminated string, so len will be smaller than size
    if( len + num_of_spaces >= size ) {
        num_of_spaces = size - len - 1;
    }  
    memset( dest+len, ' ', num_of_spaces );   
    dest[len + num_of_spaces] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although, personally I don't want helper functions. But I think I get the jest of it.  :) thanks for the help;